# не запускается catalina.bat

Tags: java, tomcat

Такая проблема. На фирме локально был поднят сайт для внутренних нужд.
На сколько я помню писался на java и поднимался через tomcat. Человек который это все делал ушел, а я ничего в этом не смыслю.
запускается он просто, в командной строке прописывается:

`cd c:\tomcat\bin & catalina start`

Появилась нужда перенести это на другую машину и соответственно возникли проблемы.
при запуске зависает и висит на одном месте.
выглядит это так:

```
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\tomcat
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\tomcat
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=c:\tomcat\conf\logging.properties
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=c:\tomcat
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=c:\tomcat
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.305 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=c:\tomcat\temp
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.445 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.539 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.539 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.539 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.539 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 598 ms
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:26.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.30
24-Nov-2023 13:40:31.275 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Nov-2023 13:40:31.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\tomcat\webapps\support.war]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.539 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.633 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\tomcat\webapps\support.war] has finished in [4,219] ms
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.633 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\tomcat\webapps\docs]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.664 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\tomcat\webapps\docs] has finished in [31] ms
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.664 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\tomcat\webapps\examples]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.898 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\tomcat\webapps\examples] has finished in [234] ms
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.914 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\tomcat\webapps\host-manager]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.930 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\tomcat\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [16] ms
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.930 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\tomcat\webapps\manager]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.945 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\tomcat\webapps\manager] has finished in [15] ms
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.961 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.961 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
24-Nov-2023 13:40:35.961 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 9423 ms
```

кто подскажет куда копать и смотреть?

при запуске сервера на новой машине файл лога не создается, на старой машине выдаёт следующее:

```
2023-11-24 14:53:03.088  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] md.support.support.SupportApplication    : Starting SupportApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 13.0.1 on vm-backup with PID 14056 (C:\tomcat\webapps\support\WEB-INF\classes started by rekatun in c:\tomcat\bin)
2023-11-24 14:53:03.104 DEBUG 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] md.support.support.SupportApplication    : Running with Spring Boot v2.4.2, Spring v5.3.3
2023-11-24 14:53:03.135  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] md.support.support.SupportApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-11-24 14:53:08.854  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-11-24 14:53:09.166  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 285 ms. Found 7 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-11-24 14:53:12.010  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@346db6c1' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-11-24 14:53:12.041  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2023-11-24 14:53:12.213  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8797 ms
2023-11-24 14:53:14.541  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-11-24 14:53:16.885  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2023-11-24 14:53:17.495  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2023-11-24 14:53:17.932  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-11-24 14:53:18.979  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-11-24 14:53:19.166  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
2023-11-24 14:53:24.291  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-11-24 14:53:55.666  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-24 14:53:56.088  WARN 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-11-24 14:54:02.260  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2023-11-24 14:54:04.588  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@15705aed, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@77a34fad, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@bc8531b, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2ffac155, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2ef9da87, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@38c91b1b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4f4be022, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@185ff681, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@39e92bbd, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@66b5474f, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@61809fc9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@4e02dd44]
2023-11-24 14:54:04.698  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2023-11-24 14:54:04.979  INFO 14056 --- [localhost-startStop-1] md.support.support.SupportApplication    : Started SupportApplication in 64.75 seconds (JVM running for 81.05)
```

Comment: Почему вы думаете что он висит? В логе какие-либо ошибки отсутствуют(ERROR), да и последнее сообщение как раз сообщает что сервер запустился.

Comment: Что копать? :)  Сервер запустился в штатном порядке.  Поскольку вы запустили его на другой машине, у вас скорее всего изменился IP-адрес / хост, по которому следует обращаться к вашему серверу.

Comment: С того что сервер не запустился, раз, два, просто наблюдение, запуск на старом компьютере проходит немного дольше и судя по тексту в командной строке по другому, ну и вишенка на торте это ошибка 404 ( Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.).

Comment: я конечно ничего не соображаю в этом, но голова на плечах присутсвует и если я обратился за помощью значит что то не работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Можете привести образец лога со старого и нового компьютера? В логе который вы предоставили ничего подозрительного нет.

Comment: Добавил в описание

Comment: Слишком много проблем, а информации полезной нет.

Comment: @МаксимКовалевский, предоставленной информации недостаточно.  Приведённые логи не содержат каких-то сообщений об ошибках, наоборот, они показывают, что сервисы/приложения запустились корректно.  Вероятно, более продуктивный путь для решения вашей проблемы -- найти соответствующую документацию по проекту либо связаться с предыдущим разработчиком, чтобы он ввёл вас более подробно в курс дела.

Comment: @Nowhere Man я вас услышал, к сожалению это вся информация которой я располагаю. Спасибо за уделенное внимание.